# How can I learn more about a deleted question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I noticed the following.

[image]

I vaguely recall that question but not more that that. However, I don't understand why I'm getting +2 for its **removal**. I'm not clear **why** it's been removed. And I definitely wish to see its contents to refresh my memory.

Nothing of that can be achieved using the usual GUI, as far I'm informed. Is there a REST'ish URL approach or maybe some kind of API that I can ask to calm my curiosity? Is it OK to ask moderators to get more info? If so, how? I can't **flag** the question, exactly...

Please note that I have no objections to it being removed. I'm just very curious why stuff happens, especially if it's unexpected and when unable to explain myself.

Comment: When a question is removed, the points you earned or lost due to it are also removed; in this case, it seems that question had got a -1 vote, and this disappeared together with the question; thus you regained the 2 points you had lost before.

Comment: @gnat I've checked the linked question but as far I can see it doesn't contain the answers to my question (especially, please view the second paragraph from the bottom).

Comment: If you wanna see the full image http://i.stack.imgur.com/JEwH0.png :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844024/how-to-explicitly-not-cascade-on-delete) of your own questions and it had a downvote (-2):
<sub>*googling for the exact title lead me to it*</sub>

> [image]

Looks like the [cleaning script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) got it:

[image]

On the Questions tab in your profile, you'll see a link "deleted recent questions":

https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=questions

Comment: Oh, now we're getting somewhere interesting. How can I learn the reason for deletion? If I'm not mistaken, the answers/comments gave me a good idea on something. I wasn't aware of auto-deletions until just now. How can I learn more?

Comment: @KonradViltersten http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year

Comment: @MartinSmith Weird... My question is dated from 21st Novemeber. A bit quickish to remove it. Also, I believe there was an answer (or at least a comment) that helped me. Could it be caused by something else? Have I formulated the question in a low-standard way?

Comment: It had no answers, just a comment so it meets the first case described in the answer there and is deleted after 30 days. You should be able to see the question yourself as described in this answer.

Comment: @MartinSmith Got it. Thanks! I got a bit confused for a moment. Still, the comments were of use to me. I even asked the commentor to repost as a reply but he never did... Sad. I don't dare to ask the same question again, though, so it'll be wisdom going lost.   :)

Answer (score 3):

You can find this by yourself in the Question list. At the bottom of the page.

Goto your profile -> Questions Section -> Then at the bottom you will find a link called [`Deleted Recent Questions`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/1525840).

I have tried to create the link for your profile. I hope you will be able to access it just by clicking on it.

---

**Edit:**
Why and When the `Community` user delete questions:

The Community user will automatically delete old abandoned/dead questions in the following circumstances:

1. If the question is more than 30 days old, and...(**I think your question falls into this category.**)

   - has −1 or lower score
   - has no answers
   - is not locked
2. If the question is more than 365 days old, and ...

   - has a score of 0, or a score of 1 in case of deleted owner
   - has no answers
   - is not locked
   - has view count <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
   - has 1 or 0 comments
3. If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...

   - not closed as a duplicate
   - has a score of 0 or less
   - is not locked
   - has no answers with a score > 0
   - has no accepted answer
   - has no pending reopen votes
   - has not been edited in the past 9 days

Each of the above reason have more specific criteria for deleting a question. You can find it here: [The Community user deleted my question! What gives?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)

Comment: @KonradViltersten I have got my answer back with some more information about when and how a question is get deleted by community user.

Comment: I liked the old version the best but this extensive one's cool too. +1